# How to make an <i> element invisible until hovered over using CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I trying to figure out how to make an  element I am using with the emoji css file (https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/) be invisible, until the A element it is attached too, is hovered over. So I want this:

```
<p><a href="#"><i class="em em-skull"> SKULL EMOJI</i></a></p>
```

And I want the skull emoji to only show up, when the anchor tag is hovered over.

Comment: `.em-skull {opacity: 0} a:hover .em-skull {opacity: 1}`

Answer (score 4):

Try `visibility` property:

```
i {
    visibility: hidden;
}

i:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set invisible the element first, there is a property called visibility:

```
a {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And then show it:

```
a:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

There are more type of event detectors, these are called Pseudo-classes, like:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<p><a href="#" class="showafterhover"><i class="em em-skull"></i>SKULL EMOJI</a></p>
```

css

```
.showafterhover>i{visibility: hidden;}
.showafterhover:hover>i{visibility: visible;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a i { display: none; } a:hover i { display: block; }
```

Try this CSS it should be work

Comment: Always try to elobrate your answer

Comment: This won't work! Why? Because `display: none` removes the element and the complete space it would take, so there is no area to hover anymore. `visibility: hidden` on the other hand only hides the element, but it still takes the space, so you can hover it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a .em {
  display: none;
}

a:hover .em {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p><a href=#><i class="em em-skull"></i>SKULL EMOJI</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.em-skull {
  visibility:hidden;
}

a:hover  > .em-skull{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://emoji-css.afeld.me/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

<p><a href="#"><i class="em em-skull"> </i>SKULL EMOJI</a></p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).